# Android Gradle tarda mucho en compilar

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

Cuando construyo o sincronizo `Gradle` en `Android Studio`, toma mucho tiempo y no estoy muy seguro de por qué sucede, intenté desinstalar y eliminar todos los archivos y luego volver a instalarlos y sigue sucediendo, sucede en todos los proyectos, incluso los reinstalé y comencé un nuevo proyecto con solo la vista de texto `"hola mundo"` y se tardó alrededor de 13 minutos en compilar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No sé si estas imágenes ayudan, esta es la construcción con el proyecto de `"Hola Mundo"` que aparece cuando recién instalas `Android Studio`.

**EDIT:**
agrego esto a ver si sirve de algo, son los procesos que mas demoraron en el `build`.

:app:transformClassesWithInstantRunVerifierForDebug 3 m 19 s 175 ms :app:transformClassesWithInstantRunForDebug 3 m 30 s 967 ms :app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug **15 m 31 s 159 ms** :app:transformDexWithInstantRunSlicesApkForDebug 1 m 6 s 762 ms

---

Windows 10, 16gb RAM, a veces solo enciendo la PC y corro el Android studio solo e igual sucede.

Comment: Saludos @waroxx . Podrías decirme por favor en que sistema operativo estas usando `AndroidStudio`? Cuanta memoria `ram` tiene tu equipo y que otros procesos estas ejecutando en simultaneo al `IDE`?

Comment: @DavidVillegas Windows 10, 16gb RAM, a veces solo enciendo la PC y corro el Android studio solo e igual sucede. BTW: gracias por las correcciones.

Comment: Cuando eliminas `AndroidStudio` solo lo des-instalas normalmente por el panel de control, o también eliminas los archivos que se crean fuera de tu disco de instalación?, los archivos que están en las carpetas ocultas i/o no ocultas, de tu carpeta de usuario.

Comment: @DavidVillegas Elimino todas las carpetas que estan relacionadas con android, hasta las ocultas, como si nunca lo hubiese instalado.

Comment: Me parece que no es cuestión de `AndroidStudio` sino de tu `PC` en si, por que por ejemplo yo uso `8GB` de `ram` y cuando mas tarda son 3 minutos y por que tengo muchísimas cosas abiertas. Y si eliminas todo como dices no sabría decirte el por que te sucede eso, y hasta ahora tampoco he visto incompatibilidades con las nuevas versiones de `Gradle` o del `IDE` con `Windows 10`

Comment: @DavidVillegas interesante deducción, creo que tendre que a formatear o revisar por algun virus. Tambien añado que uso otros IDE como Visual Studio y no tienen ningun problema.

Comment: Para gradle es más importante la CPU que la memoria RAM, que CPU tienes?
Y con que versión de android studio, la 3.2 es más rapido
Te dejo ese enlace si te sirve: https://medium.com/@wasyl/make-your-gradle-builds-fast-again-ea323ce6a435